# Choropleth zip code

Tags: r, zipcode, choropleth

I'm trying to create a choropleth of Zip Codes in part of Virginia to show some company data. I can get everything to run correctly except the last line `aes(fill = growth)`. There, I get an error:

> Error: Aesthetics must either be length one, or the same length as the dataProblems:growth

Here's my data:

- [A Shapefile of northern Virginia zip codes](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B47JVhU8sqbmb1o4Y2I2Ml9aZkU/view?usp=sharing)
- [A csv](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B47JVhU8sqbmUGJsN3RFV3htb2M/view?usp=sharing) of the zipcodes I'm interested in and the corresponding company data values.

My code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(maptools)
library(rgdal)
library(plyr)

#set working directory
setwd("F:/Dropbox/Zip Codes")

#load Shapefile NOVA
Zips <- readOGR(dsn="F:/Dropbox/Zip Codes", layer="NOVA")

#load Company Data of Zip Codes
Company <- read.csv("Data.csv")

#set to data.frame
Company_df <- data.frame(Company)

#create growth vector
growth = Company_df[,'Growth']

#merge growth vector into Zips
Zips$growth = growth

#ggplot
Nmap = ggplot(Zips) +
aes(x = long, y = lat, group=group) +
geom_polygon() +
aes(fill = growth)
Nmap
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I organized your directory structure a bit differently. Despite older code snippets on the internets, you don't need to bind the data to the data frame. But, you *do* need to `fortify` polygons to use with ggplot. Also, `read.csv` makes a data.frame, so you don't need to re-make one from that call.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(maptools)
library(rgdal)
library(ggthemes)

setwd("~/Development/nova_choro")

zips <- readOGR(dsn="zip_codes/NOVA.shp", layer="NOVA")
company <- read.csv("data.csv")

# this makes the polygons usable to ggplot2
# and by using ZCTA5CE10 as the region id, 
# you can then use that equivalent id field 
# from the actual company data frame for the
# choropleth colors

zips_map <- fortify(zips, region="ZCTA5CE10")

gg <- ggplot()
# draw the base map polygons
gg <- gg + geom_map(data=zips_map, map=zips_map,
                    aes(x=long, y=lat, map_id=id),
                    color="#7f7f7f", fill="white", size=0.25)
# fill in the polygons
gg <- gg + geom_map(data=company, map=zips_map,
                    aes(fill=Growth, map_id=zip_code_area),
                    color="#7f7f7f", size=0.25)
# better color scheme
gg <- gg + scale_fill_distiller(palette="Greens")
# no "slashes" in the legend boxes
gg <- gg + guides(fill=guide_legend(override.aes=list(colour=NA)))
# use an actual projection (there may be a better one for NOVA
gg <- gg + coord_map()
# get rid of map chart junk
gg <- gg + theme_map()
gg
```

[image]

I did some checking and VA uses a modified Lambert Conic Conformal projection, so you can substitute the default Mercator `coord_map` with `gg <- gg + coord_map("lambert", lat0=38.34427, lat1=39.14084)` if you like and that should be close enough to what the official agencies use.

Comment: Clear and extremely useful. Thank you immensely.